# PHP error 508 Loop detected when loading images from directory

Tags: php

I have a following code from where I am displaying an image to the front end. The problem is, sometimes its giving an error **508 Loop detected**. I don't understand why PHP is giving this error because I am not using any loop in my code. can you please help me? what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$w = $_GET['w'] ;
$fromfile = $_GET['fromfile']  ;

if(isset($_GET['fromfile']))    $_GET['fromfile'] = str_replace('..', '', $_GET['fromfile'] );

if(!isset($_GET['fromfile'])) {
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    echo @imagepng(@ErrorPNG("params empty"));
    exit;
} elseif (!file_exists($_GET['fromfile']))  {
    
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    echo @imagepng(@ErrorPNG("NO PIC AVAILABLE"));
    exit;
}

if(function_exists('imagetypes')) {

    if(!isset($_GET['w'])) $w=100;                                          
    $h = $w;                                                                    
    
    $img=@getimagesize("./".$fromfile);                                         
    
    if($img[0]>$w || $img[1]>$h) {
        if($img[0]>=$img[1])    {                                               
            $ratio = floatval($img[0]/$w);
            $h = ceil($img[1]/$ratio);
            }
        else if($img[1]>$img[0]) {                                              
            $ratio = floatval($img[1]/$h);
            $w = ceil($img[0]/$ratio);
        }
    }
    else {                                                                      
        $w = $img[0];
        $h = $img[1];
    }
    
    if(is_array($img)) {
        switch($img[2]) {
            case 1 :
            if(!(imagetypes() & IMG_GIF)) {
                if(!function_exists("imagecreatefromgif")) $nomanage=true;  

                else {
                    $outype="png";                      
                    $img['mime']="image/png";
                }
            } else $outype="gif";
            $imtype="gif";
            break;
            case 2 :
            if(!(imagetypes() & IMG_JPG)) $nomanage=true;
            $outype="jpeg";
            $imtype="jpeg";
            break;
            case 3 :
            if(!(imagetypes() & IMG_PNG)) $nomanage=true;
            $imtype="png";
            $outype="png";
            break;
            default :
            header("Content-type: image/png");                              
            echo imagepng(ErrorPNG("wrong img type"));                      
            exit;
        }
        
    } else {
        header("Content-type: image/png");                                  

        echo imagepng(ErrorPNG("not image type"));
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $nomanage=true;
    $img=@getimagesize("./".$fromfile);                                 
}
if($nomanage) {
    header("Content-type: ".$img['mime']);                              
    echo join('',@file($fromfile));                                     
    exit;
}


$ou = @imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);                                     
@imagealphablending($ou, false);                                        

$funcall="imagecreatefrom$imtype";                                      
@imagecopyresampled($ou,@$funcall("./".$fromfile),
0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$img[0],$img[1]);                                         
$funcall="image$outype";                                                
@$funcall($ou,"./uploaded/cache/".md5($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));       
header("Content-type: ".$img['mime']);                                  
@$funcall($ou);                                                         


?>
```

In front end part I am providing the above code URL to the `src` attribute of a `<img />` tag where I am displaying the multiple images. Can you please help  me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I can’t comment on the error, but I can spot some bugs. You are assigning `$fromfile`, then modifying the original source, then you use both later. Also, `imagepng` and others output the image for you and return a Boolean, which your code is then echoing. Lastly, `is_array($img)` is always true at that point, so that should probably be moved up.

Comment: Okay, not a bug exactly, but `@` isn’t magic, you still need to test for `false` or whatever the failure value is. Not doing so can _lead_ to annoying and hard to find bugs.

Comment: @Chris Haas thanks for your reply. What exactly happening is. if I inspect the `src` URL of an broken image (image which not found) from browser and copy it and then if i visit that broken image url from another tab then the image is showing.